# The following StateError was thrown building Sparkline(dirty):Bad state: No element

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I need to draw a sparkline , the input of the data is from the sqlite database , I don't know why it gives me that error please could someone help me , I'm trying to count the orders to each day by using this request : 'SELECT count(id_commande) AS count, date FROM commandes group by date;'
and this is my database class :

```
class Commandes extends Table{
  IntColumn get idCommande => integer().autoIncrement()();

  IntColumn get Clientid => integer().customConstraint('REFERENCES clients(idClient)')();

  TextColumn get date => text().withLength(min: 1, max: 5000000)();
}
```

And to extract data from database I used this code

```
Future<List<int>> NombreCommandeParDate() async {
    final dao = Provider.of<CommandeDao>(context);
    var liste2 = <int>[];
    List<NombreCommandeParDateResult> liste =  await dao.NombreCommandeParDate();
    for(int i=0 ; i<liste.length; i++)
      {
        liste2.add(liste[i].count);
      }
    return liste2;
  }
```

and to read the Future data I used FutureBuilder

```
 FutureBuilder<List<int>> (
                        future: NombreCommandeParDate(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot){
                          if(snapshot.hasData){
                            commandes = snapshot.data;
                            commandes1 = new List<double>.from(commandes);

                            return Text('success !!' , style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 20.0));
                          }
                          else
                            return Text("pas de data ");
                        },
                      ),
```

and this part to draw the sparkline

```
Sparkline
                        (
                        data: commandes1,
                        lineWidth: 5.0,
                        lineColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                      )
```